# Cannot import tensorflow in python3 and ImportError: This package should not be accessible on Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, tensorflow

I am trying to use tensorflow for research in my macbook. I use pip3 to install tensorflow in the system (not in virtual environment).

At first, I just want to verify tensorflow can be correctly imported via python3 in terminal. However, sometimes, I got the following problem when importing.

```
>>>import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/cyan/Library/Python/3.5/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/Users/cyan/Library/Python/3.5/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
import numpy as np
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
from . import add_newdocs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
from .type_check import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
from . import multiarray
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PyBuffer_Type
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so
  Expected in: flat namespace in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so
```

This error could only be solved if I ran the following code firstly before python3 execution

```
unset PYTHONPATH
```

If I didn't unset PYTHONPATH, I also found errors when checking the version of pip3 using

```
pip3 --version
```

The errors are shown as follows.

```
>> pip3 --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 6, in <module>
from pip._internal import main
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
from pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
from .connectionpool import (
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 11, in <module>
from .exceptions import (
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/exceptions.py", line 2, in <module>
from .packages.six.moves.http_client import (
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 203, in load_module
mod = mod._resolve()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 115, in _resolve
return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 82, in _import_module
__import__(name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/http/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
raise ImportError('This package should not be accessible on Python 3. '
ImportError: This package should not be accessible on Python 3. Either you are trying to run from the python-future src folder or your installation of python-future is corrupted.
```

I thought it was so inconvenient to unset PYTHONPATH every time, so is there any solutions for this problem? I also want to import tensorflow in other text editor, such as Sublime and Pycharm, so I was really not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same scenario. It is working fine for me. In the first error it seems your python installation is messed up. If you are using python3 in terminal, it should not refer to 2.7 libraries.

Also I dont think you require unset PYTHONPATH everytime. First thing is you dont need to setup PYTHONPATH. It seems the installation got issue.

You using homebrew in mac to install packages. If not I will say use homebrew and it will work as charm. As it adds dependency properly.

Thanks,
Ashish